# Putting SQL record values in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL isn't my expertise but, how do I write a SQL query that takes values from two different records and put them in one row? For example, I did a query on this `EmployeeId`, and I need the output values specifically from the `Vacation_Type` column for Adjust on `2016-07-01` (if it exists) and the Forward value from date `2016-08-01` (exists for every employee) ? Desired output would be:

```
26, SL, 547.58, -37.42
```

[image: Query Output]

Not every employee would have an Adjust record, they have an Adjust when they are over the sick leave cap... and not everyone is over the cap. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    EV.EmployeeID,
    EV.Vacation_Kind,
    stuff( (    select ', ' + convert(varchar(30), EV1.Value) from EmployeeVacations EV1
                where EV1.EmployeeID = EV.EmployeeID and EV1.Vacation_Kind = EV.Vacation_Kind
                and EV1.VacationType in ('Adjust','Forward') and EV1.CreationDate IN (EV.CreationDate, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(month, 1, EV.CreationDate)), 0))
                 for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
from
    EmployeeVacations EV
where
    EV.EmployeeID = 26 and EV.Vacation_Kind = 'SL'and VacationType = 'Adjust'
group by
    EV.EmployeeID, EV.Vacation_Kind, EV.CreationDate
```

Comment: That one worked perfect after I removed the "where EV.EmployeeID = 26" and got all the records I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the 'Adjust' record isn't guaranteed to be there, you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  The following queries all employees, but you can uncomment the two lines if you really only want employee 26...

```
SELECT 
    CAST(fwd.EmployeeId AS varchar) + ', ' + 
    fwd.Vacation_Kind + ', ' + 
    CAST(fwd.[Value] as varchar) +  
    CASE WHEN adj.Value IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' + CAST(adj.Value AS varchar) END
FROM 
    @employeeVacations fwd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @employeeVacations adj ON 
        adj.EmployeeId = fwd.EmployeeId)
        AND 
        adj.Vacation_Kind = 'SL')
        AND 
        adj.Vacation_Type = 'Adjust'
        AND 
        adj.CreationDate = '2016-07-01'
WHERE 
    --fwd.EmployeeId = 26 
    --AND 
    fwd.Vacation_Kind = 'SL' 
    AND 
    fwd.Vacation_Type = 'Forward'
    AND 
    fwd.CreationDate = '2016-08-01'
```